# Como funciona o elemento <template> do HTML5?

Tags: html5

Recentemente eu vi algumas notícias sobre um novo elemento HTML chamado `<template>` especificado pela W3C e que já foi implementado em grande parte dos navegadores mais modernos.

Aparentemente ele permite a criação de tags customizadas, mais ou menos como no XML:

```
<minha-tag>
    <!-- -->
</minha-tag>
```

Mas ainda não ficou claro para mim o que exatamente ele trás de benefícios e até que ponto essa criação de tags te permite ir.

Então, quais seriam as vantagens de se utilizar este novo elemento? Quando e onde o seu uso é mais aconselhado?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Funciona assim: 
Tudo que está entre `<template>` e `</template>` é ignorado pelo navegador na hora de renderizar a página. Até ai funciona quase como se fosse um comentário. Só que tem uma difrença: dentro da tag template, você pode por HTML válido, cujo conteúdo vai ser completado por algum script depois que a página for carregada.

Ou seja: o tag template serve para declarar trechos de HTML que serão ignorados pelo navegador, mas estarão disponiveis para serem usados por scripts naquela página. Esses scripts, podem, por exemplo, recuperar o conteúdo do atributo `content` do objeto `template`, e usar o método  `cloneNode` - ex.:

```js
function preenche() {
  var nomes = ["Bruno", "Daniel", "Marcelo"]
  var template = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
    var texto = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    texto.querySelectorAll("spam")[0].textContent = nomes[i];
    document.body.appendChild(texto);
  }

}

preenche();
```

```html
<body>
  <template>
           <p>
           Bem-vindo <spam></spam>
           </p>
       </template>


</body>
```

Ou seja: você só vai usar se estiver codificando Javascript que vai preencher, usando DOM, e não substituição de textos, valores para aparecerem na página depois que ela for carregada. No trecho acima, os nomes estão pré-codificados - mas eles podem ser obtidos com uma chamada Ajax.

Na prática, em quase todas as págians e aplicações WEB que criamos, ou o  framework no lado do servidor é que gera o HTML formatado, ou o javascript cria o HTML dos dados de Ajax usando DOM, ou substituição de textos. Com o tag `<template>`, pode-se escreverum javascript mais limpo para formatar os dados obtidos por ajax.

A documentação oficial do tag `template` está aqui:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html/scripting-1.html#the-template-element

Comment: Aqui tem um [exemplo simples](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/sge4u0y7/)